# the number of possible paths in graph

Tags: c++, graph

I have to calculate the number of possible paths in undirected graph
Example: I have a undirected graph with 4 node. The vertices: **1->2;** **2>3;** **2->4**.
So the number of possible paths is **12**

```
(1->2;  1->2->3;  1->2->4;  2->1;  2->3;  2->4;  3->2;  3->2->4...and so on);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where's the code?  What did it do right, and where did it fall over (i.e. for which paths)?  What don't you understand about why it falls over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't know exactly how you wrote your code, all I can give you is some sort of a pseudo-code explanation :

```
function getPathsFromNode(node)
    mark node
    c = 0;

    foreach neighbour in adjacent nodes of node
        if neighbour is not marked
            c += getPathsFromNode(neighbour) + 1

    return c


function main()
    n = 0
    foreach node in graph
        n += getPathsFromNode(node)

    print("paths = ", n)
```

Basically it's just a [**DFS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for every node of the graph.

Comment: the complexity of the code is gonna be O(V²+VE). It is so slow